# Create a tree using struct and for loops in C

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree, return-value, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a question. I'm trying to create a tree. The full code is large so it is difficult for me to enter here. So a summary of it is given below.

```c
struct sample *fn_02(void);
struct sample *fn_03(void);

// Main Function
int main(void) {
    struct sample *tree;

    tree = fn_01();
}

// First Function
struct sample *fn_01(void) {
    for(;;) {
        switch(..) {
            case 1:
                return fn_02();

            case 2:
                return fn_03();
        }
    }
}

// Second Function
struct sample *fn_02(void) {
    struct sample *node;

    return node;
}

// Third Function
struct sample *fn_03(void) {
    struct sample *node;

    return node;
}
```

I want to create a tree. So I create a structure called `struct sample {};` and create a 3 functions for it.

There is an infinity loop in the first ( `fn_01()` ) function and The values returned by `fn_02` and `fn_03` should create a tree.

This is the problem I have:

- The loop in `fn_01` should continue to work.
- But when `fn_02` and `fn_03` are returned the loop ( and function ) stops.
- But a return is essential to creating the tree. And the for loop must continue to work.

Can you suggest another solution to do this please?

Comment: please explain in words how this "infinity loop" is supposed to work? How do you make an infinite tree?

Comment: If you want to return a value, it'll return and end the function. What exactly should these functions do? I feel like there's an XY problem here, so more explanation of the actual issue might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without seeing more codes, but you probably may handle that by postponing the return statement :

```
struct sample *fn_01(void) {
    sample * s = NULL;
    for(;;) {
        switch(..) {
            case 1:
                s = fn_02();
                break;
            case 2:
                s = fn_03();
                break;
        }
        // Check s and/or do something with it. Return only when relevant
    }
}
```